# Make Chart.js chart stretch to 100% width without inside padding

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

Is it possible to make a Chart.js graph utilize the full width of the page as the containing div does?

[image]

The canvas element is placed in a containing div that stretches 100% of the viewport. Is there an option to remove the inside padding that Chart.js adds?

I've tried offsetting the labels with a negative number but with no success.

The canvas that the graph is placed:

```
<canvas id="save-simulator" class="graph"></canvas>
```

My code:

```
        const ChartObj = new Chart(element, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            onClick: this.handleClick.bind(this, chartData),
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                        zeroLineColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', // hide the zero line by making it white
                        zeroLineWidth: 0,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        // Only display time line with a 5 year span
                        callback: function(dataLabel, index) {
                            return (index+1) % 5 === 0 ? dataLabel : '';
                        },
                    }
                }],
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
                position: 'nearest',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        if (data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label.length) {
                            return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + currencyFormatter.format(tooltipItem.yLabel, { code: 'SEK', thousand: ' ', precision: 0 });
                        }
                    },
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data.labels[tooltipItem[0]['index']] + ' år';
                    }
                },
            }
        },
    });
```

Comment: By default, the interior of the chart has a padding value of 0.  The image that you shared in your questions looks like it has padding 0 as well.  The reason for the gap is because the x axis label extends beyond the chart area.  See how the "45" sits right on the border of the div/page?

Comment: That is correct, however I have tried offsetting the x axis labels with -10 px but the padding remains. I can not find anything in their documentation that suggest anything else.

Comment: Ok I see now, you are really wanting to know how to adjust the position of the scale tick labels so that your chart can fill the entire area.  Let me play around with it.

Comment: I've spent quite a lot of time digging around in the source and it looks like even if padding and margins are set to 0, chart.js calculates a minimum padding on the left/right to ensure that text does not overflow the canvas.  Short of trying to modify `Chart.layoutService.update()` (where all the fitting magic happens), I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you @jordanwillis for your help.

Comment: @Gomer Hi, do you find the solution for this problem ??

Comment: Also curious, any updates on this? @Gomer

Comment: @Roy We actually decided to use another chart library that fit our needs better.

Answer (score 0):

The padding could be caused by the `x` scale offset. If this property is set to true, extra space is added to both edges and the axis is scaled to fit into the chart area. This property is set to true for a bar chart by default.

Set `scales[x].offset`, as defined [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes), to `false`.

You could, alternatively, also disable the default layout padding, [reference](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html#layout)

Answer (score 0):

I found setting

```
options.maintainAspectRatio : false
```

Did the job for me. Freeing the chart from a fixed aspect ratio meant it could take up the space. It seems that padding is 0 by default?

I had to go hunting in the api docs to find this - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/api/interfaces/CoreChartOptions.html#maintainaspectratio